# Insert MIME type of an URL into Apache's access_log

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files, mime-type

I would like to enhance my logfile with an additional field containing the mime type.
E.G.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2012:20:49:36 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 255 [...] "text/html"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2012:20:49:37 +0100] "GET /x.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1022 [...] "image/gif"
```

I could not find a standard field for this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can log any header field that is present in the response, like so: `%{HEADER_NAME}o`. In this case, **`%{Content-Type}o`** covers the MIME type as well.

Refer to the [**Custom Log Formats**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) documentation for details.

Comment: I guess the header you would want would be `Content-Type:` so in CustomLog: `"%{Content-Type}i"`.  It *does* contain more than just the MIME type, however.  Wrapped in quotes because the header can contain spaces.

Comment: The "i" at the end of {HEADER_NAME} is wrong, but I figured out that I need to replace it with an "o". (like "incoming" and "outgoing")

Comment: Ah, excellent, sorry about that.